# Open up two tabs in a new chrome incognito window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to open up a new incognito window in chrome with two tabs.  I have:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
                      'active': true,
                      'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
                  },
                  function(tabs) {
                      var url = tabs[0].url;
                      chrome.windows.create({"url": url,
                                             "incognito": true});
                  }
);
```

But I am not sure on how to add a chrome.tabs to open google.com in a new tab in the same incognito tab.

Is that possible?

Also, I cannot gain focus on an incognito window. I can gain the focus when I leave off 'incgonito': true but not when I add it like so:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
                  'active': true,
                  'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
                  },
                  function(tabs) {
                      var url = tabs[0].url;
                      var urlIntent = "http://google.com";
                      chrome.windows.create({
                                             "url": url,
                                             focused: true,
                                             "incognito": true
                                             },
                                             function(window){
                                                chrome.windows.update(
                                                        window.id, 
                                                        {focused: true})
                                             });
                  }
);
```

Comment: I was able to bring the incognito window focused as so...First I named the window by: `chrome.windows.create(function(window){window.name = "portal";});` then `code'window.open("", "portal").focus();` But I still need to open up that second tab if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest.json you need to add:

```
      "incognito":"split",
```

As shown here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito